# Safe to use this narrowing 2" PVC extension in shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain, pvc

After leveling shower floor for new shower base, I need to raise height of 2" drain pipe about 1.75" to accommodate a "no-caulk" base drain. The pipe is buried in concrete foundation.

I found a pipe extender marketed for pool plumbing with a 1.25" L narrow end that fits inside the 2" pipe, and gives me an extra 1.25" of height.

This reduces a portion of the internal diameter of the pipe to roughly 1.75". Will that quarter inch loss be significant enough to slow drainage in a meaningful way? Once it's in and shower redone, there's no going back!

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you plan to connect them to make it leak tight

Comment: @knowitall - PVC cement, but I've never worked with PVC before, so open to better ideas.

Comment: what about going the other way, slip a 2" extender over the 2" pipe, how much pipe is sticking out of the concrete ?

Comment: @knowitall - only 1" above concrete. Not sure it would work. Drain tops made for acrylic shower bases that I've found are made to go on the outside of 2" pipes.

Comment: So it might work with 2 in. PVC Schedule 40 S x S Coupling, without using glue, glue scares me, it is so permanent. Since it is not a pressure pipe you might get away with just a o-ring

Comment: "Get away with" and "Meeting plumbing code" don't go well together. If PVC cement scares you, don't do PVC plumbing anywhere that plumbing code applies.

Comment: the answer below from @ecnerwal is correct. Use a 2" slip by slip coupling to properly extend the riser pipe length. It must be chiselled into the concrete so only the 2" pipe sticks up to accept the shower pan "no caulk" gasket. The shower pan gasket will not work over the outside diameter of a 2" coupling.

Comment: @Kyle - Thanks. Not enough room for slip x slip, and trying to avoid undoing and redoing the concrete/leveling. Found a video by a plumber demonstrating how to remove glued pipe from fitting, by making multiple cuts in the pipe, then gently prying out each part. https://youtu.be/-CpgYUpNXaQ?t=799  -- Thoughts?

Comment: The riser 2" pipe extends about an inch out of an elbow fitting, just barely peaking out of the concrete. Slip x Slip plus another one to two inches needed for the no-caulk gasket would be too high.

Comment: OK- I see better now. I still think you will need to remove some concrete- not sure you can get that small piece of pipe out and another in with the concrete encasing it. I guess you could try...It seems you do need to remove that pipe from the fitting below (however you can) and extend it up to the proper height. A tricky deal to remove the pipe without damaging the fitting in the concrete...

Comment: @Kyle - added photo of the fitting in place. But I think you've already understood. Scary because if I fail, I loose the opportunity to use the initial approach (even though it's risky, not up to code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 1.75" .vs. 2" significant? (if schedule 40, as is likely/common, actually 2.067" ID for the drain pipe)

Math makes all clear. If you want to do the whole thing, the area of the pipes are Pi * r**2 (Pi r-squared) though the *relationship* (which is all we really need to know) is the same if you just look at d**2

1.75 squared is 3.0625

2 squared is 4

2.067 squared is 4.272489

So your reducer is 71.68% of 2" schedule 40 pipe. Or reduces the area by 28.32% if you prefer that view.

More simply, most plumbing codes **require** a 2" shower drain, so if you need to chisel a bit into the concrete to do the extension correctly to code, get chiseling, because it's going to be **a major bother** to have to remove the shower if your inspector fails it after you've installed a non-approved part. Chiseling concrete looks *easy* by comparison.

Comment: trying to avoid undoing and redoing the concrete/leveling. Found a video by a plumber demonstrating how to remove glued pipe from fitting, by making multiple cuts in the pipe, then gently prying out each part. Thoughts? youtu.be/-CpgYUpNXaQ?t=799

Comment: Heatgun and pliers works easier, IME. But you might want to practice a bit before going at your actual cemented in place fitting.